# What is a good practice for redirecting in an angular SPA

Tags: angularjs, redirect

I am building an angular app and have encountered several instances where I would like to redirect the user to a certain page. But that information about whether a user should be redirected or not is typically received after a server side request.

In the time it takes to do a server request, the original page starts rendering and hence creates a bad UX.

A case in point would be redirecting to login page when user is unauthorized.

**Question 1** I know how to handle these cases individually. But was wondering if there is some standard pattern I can follow to solve this issue.

**Question 2** Is there a standard pattern to control when to start rendering the page when information is being fetched from server. for instance 
my view has

```
{{user.name}}
```

and controller has following code:

```
userService.load_user().then(function(user) {
    $scope.user = user;
});
```

I don't want anything displayed till user is loaded, maybe just a loading sign. Currently i can do it as such:

```
//controller
userService.load_user().then(function(user) {
    $scope.user = user;
    $scope.loaded = true;
});
```

and

```
<!-- view -->
<div ng-show="!loaded">
    <img src="loading.gif"/>
</div>
<div ng-show="loaded">
    real code here.
</div>
```

This gets complicated when I want to wait on more than one requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the resolve property of the routes. Am assuming you're using ngRoutes or ui-router. Both include the resolve property on their routes.

To add a spinner or something similar while you wait for them to resolve, listen for the view change events within the shell view controller (assuming you have one) and add/remove the spinner accordingly.

By shell controller I just mean the highest level view within which the others are nested. It may or may not have a controller, but usually does. You might have a `showSpinner` property on that scope:

```
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.showSpinner = false;

    $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(){
        $scope.showSpinner = true;
    });
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(){
        $scope.showSpinner = false;
    });
});
```

Then you could just use `ng-show='showSpinner'` or `ng-show='!showSpinner'` on the spinner html element and the view element respectively.

This is the basic idea. You will probably end up with something more elaborate.

[Here is a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YLOPZjZyQdBikQpRc12O). There is a little more going on there (abstract state etc) than you requested, but you will quickly see how the resolve property is used and how the state is diverted.

Comment: How did I miss resolve. Thanks, thats great help. Not sure what you mean by "shell view controller". can you elaborate please? (Waiting for this before accepting the answer)